# What tools to use in Visual Studio 2012 for making a web forum?

Tags: asp.net, forum

I'm working on a project that requires me to make a simple "social network" using ASP.Net in Visual Studio 2012.

I have my website layed out how I need it and even have a log in/register system set up.

I need to be able to have registered users to initiate topics, or join the existing discussion page.

Essentially what I'm looking for is just a very basic forum type structure.

Do I need to use some things from the Toolbox to do this? I'm pretty new to this ASP stuff and could use some help.

Thanks

Comment: See this link http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/blog-engine it provide full-featured blogging platform.

Comment: another link for forum http://yetanotherforum.net/features.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel from scratch.  Web PI have forum applications you can use.

From Microsoft Web Site:

The [Microsoft Web Platform Installer (Web PI)](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) is a free tool that makes getting the latest components of the Microsoft Web Platform, including Internet Information Services (IIS), SQL Server Express, .NET Framework and Visual Web Developer easy. The Web PI also makes it easy to install and run the most popular free web applications for blogging, content management and more with the built-in [Windows Web Application Gallery](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/).

[image: Screen shot of Web PI]